# Can I use the style of iOS 6 UITabBar?

Tags: ios, ios6, uitabbar

In iOS 6, the UITabBar has a different style (like in the App Store). Is it a predefined style that we can use or is it just a customized tab bar?
I had a look at the [UITabBar reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but I didn't find anything that looks like predefined style.

Edit:

I just made a new tab bar app using iOS 6 SDK, targeting only iOS 6 and the tab bar style is the old one.

The style I get :

[image]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Art/tabbar.png))</sub>

The style I would like to get :

[image]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Art/ui_selecteditemmodeswitcher.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customise the tabbar via [appearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007521-CH3-SW4) available in iOS 5+

Comment: my bad.. its not the default as i thought. U will need to customise it using appearance as i mentioned. check this link http://felipecypriano.com/2012/02/27/how-to-customize-uitabbar-on-ios-5/